# Confluent Kafka JDBC Source to Oracle EBR table

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Confluent JDBC Source (Confluent 5.5) cannot detect a table with EBR (Edition Based Redefinition) from Oracle:

Config:

```
{ 
   "name": "source-oracle-bulk2", 
   "config": { 
      "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector", 
      "tasks.max": 4, 
      "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:1521/service",
      "connection.user": "user",
      "connection.password": "passw",
      "mode": "bulk", 
      "topic.prefix": "oracle-bulk-",
      "numeric.mapping": "best_fit",
      "poll.interval.ms": 60000,
      "table.whitelist" : "SCHEMA1.T1"
   } 
}
```

Connect log:

```
connect            | [2020-07-20 17:24:09,156] WARN No tasks will be run because no tables were found (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector)
```

With Query it successfully ingests data:

```
{ 
   "name": "source-oracle-bulk1", 
   "config": { 
      "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector", 
      "tasks.max": 1, 
      "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:1521/service",
      "connection.user": "user",
      "connection.password": "pass",
      "mode": "bulk", 
      "topic.prefix": "oracle-bulk-T1",
      "numeric.mapping": "best_fit",
      "poll.interval.ms": 60000,
      "dialect.name" : "OracleDatabaseDialect",
      "query": "SELECT * FROM SCHEMA1.T1"
   } 
}
```

Could it be that "table.types" should be specified for some specific type ?

I tried "VIEW" but it just cannot create a Source and fails with timeout: {"error_code":500,"message":"Request timed out"}

Comment: Try to add `schema.pattern` property

Comment: Yep, fixed the timeout with schema.pattern (got it myself, but thanks for the suggestion). So far I made it working with "table.types" : "TABLE,VIEW,ALIAS,SYNONYM". But that's just magic since the table is just suffixed with '#' and has no special type